# Livewire Form not submitting

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a little bit of an issue regarding my form, it is not submitting. I have a table of records and I have a form attached in the last row that will only appear after clicking a show button. it is working now however my problem is that the form is not submitting, and I found out in the inspect element that the input elements are not inside of the form tag. but in code the input tags are within the form. Please see details below

[image: The view]

[image: After clicking the add product]

Code of the view:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="background-color: #24d5b8" colspan="6">LIST OF INCOMING PRODUCTS</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="wd-15p">PRODUCT</th>
                <th class="wd-15p">UOM</th>
                <th class="wd-15p">QUANTITY</th>
                <th class="wd-15p">UNIT COST</th>
                <th class="wd-15p">TOTAL COST</th>
                <th class="wd-10p">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @forelse($products as $index => $product)
                <tr wire:key="product-list-{{ $index }}">
                    <td>
                        @if ($editedProductIndex !== $index)
                            {{ $product['product']['product_name'] }}
                        @else
                            {{-- <div wire:ignore>
                                <select wire:model.defer="products.{{ $index }}.product_id" id="product_id"
                                    class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Select Product</option>
                                    @foreach ($products as $product)
                                        <option value="{{ $product->id }}">{{ $product->product_name }}
                                        </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div> --}}
                            <input type="text" wire:model.defer="products.{{ $index }}.product_id">
                            @error('editedProduct.product_id')
                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if ($editedProductIndex !== $index)
                            {{ $product['uom'] ?? 'UNIT' }}
                        @else
                            {{-- <div wire:ignore>
                                <select wire:model.defer="editedProduct.uom" id="uom" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Select UOM</option>
                                    @foreach ($uoms as $uom)
                                        <option value="{{ $uom->id }}">{{ $uom->uom_name }}
                                        </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div> --}}
                            <input type="text" name="" id=""
                                wire:model.defer="products.{{ $index }}.uom">
                            @error('editedProduct.uom')
                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if ($editedProductIndex !== $index)
                            {{ $product['quantity'] }}
                        @else
                            <input type="text" wire:model.defer="products.{{ $index }}.quantity"
                                class="form-control">
                            @error('editedProduct.quantity')
                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if ($editedProductIndex !== $index)
                            {{ $product['unit_cost'] }}
                        @else
                            <input type="text" wire:model.defer="products.{{ $index }}.unit_cost"
                                class="form-control">
                            @error('editedProduct.unit_cost')
                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if ($editedProductIndex !== $index)
                            {{ $product['total_cost'] }}
                        @else
                            <input type="text" wire:model.defer="products.{{ $index }}.total_cost"
                                class="form-control">
                            @error('editedProduct.total_cost')
                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if ($editedProductIndex !== $index)
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info-light button-icon btn-md"
                                data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-bs-original-title="EDIT"
                                wire:click.prevent="editProduct({{ $index }})"><i
                                    class="fe fe-edit"></i></button>
                        @else
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info-light button-icon btn-md"
                                data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-bs-original-title="SAVE"
                                wire:click.prevent="updateProduct({{ $index }})"><i
                                    class="fe fe-save"></i></button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info-light button-icon" data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                                title="" data-bs-original-title="CANCEL"
                                wire:click.prevent="cancelProductEdit({{ $index }})">
                                <i class="fe fe-x"></i>
                            </button>
                        @endif
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @empty
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6" class="text-center">No products found.</td>
                </tr>
            @endforelse

            @if ($showAddForm)
                <tr wire:ignore>
                    <form wire:submit.prevent="storeProductItems">
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <select wire:model="selectedProduct" id="selectedProduct" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Select Product</option>
                                    @foreach ($product_list as $product)
                                        <option value="{{ $product->id }}">{{ $product->product_name }}
                                        </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            @error('selectedProduct')
                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <select wire:model.defer="unit_of_measure_item_id" id="unit_of_measure_item_id"
                                    class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Select UOM</option>
                                    @foreach ($uoms as $uom)
                                        <option value="{{ $uom->id }}">{{ $uom->uom_name }}
                                        </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            @error('unit_of_measure_item_id')
                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </td>
                        <td><input wire:model.defer="quantity" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td><input wire:model.defer="unit_cost" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td><input wire:model.defer="total_cost" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info-light button-icon btn-md"
                                data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-bs-original-title="SAVE"><i
                                    class="fe fe-save"></i></button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info-light button-icon" data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                                title="" data-bs-original-title="DELETE" wire:click="cancelAddProduct">
                                <i class="fe fe-x"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </form>
                </tr>
            @else
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6" class="align-item-left">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" wire:click="addProduct">Add Product</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endif
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

@push('jsplugins')
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/plugins/select2/js/select2.min.js') }}"></script>
@endpush

@push('scripts')
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('select2', event => {
            $('#selectedProduct').select2();

            $('#selectedProduct').on('change', function(e) {
                @this.set('selectedProduct', e.target.value);
            });

            $('#unit_of_measure_item_id').select2();

            $('#unit_of_measure_item_id').on('change', function(e) {
                @this.set('unit_of_measure_item_id', e.target.value);
            });
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

The livewire component class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Inventory\Shipment;

use App\Models\Admin\UnitOfMeasureItems;
use App\Models\Inventory\Product;
use App\Models\Inventory\Shipment\IncomingStockProduct;
use Livewire\Component;

class IncomingStockProducts extends Component
{
    public $editedProductIndex = null;
    public $incoming_stock;
    public $products = [];
    public $uoms;
    public $product_list;

    public $selectedProduct = null, $unit_of_measure_item_id, $quantity, $unit_cost, $total_cost;

    public $showAddForm = false;

    protected $listeners = [
        'selectedProduct'
    ];

    public function mount($incoming_stock)
    {
        $this->incoming_stock = $incoming_stock;
        $this->products = $this->incoming_stock->IncomingStockProducts->load('product')->toArray();
        $this->product_list = Product::all();
        $this->uoms = collect();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.inventory.shipment.incoming-stock-products');
    }

    public function updatedSelectedProduct($product_id)
    {
        if (!is_null($product_id)) {
            $uom = Product::where('id', $product_id)->first();
            $this->uoms = UnitOfMeasureItems::where('unit_of_measure_id', $uom->unit_of_measure_id)->get();
        }
    }

    public function hydrate()
    {
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('select2');
    }



    public function editProduct($productIndex)
    {
        $this->showAddForm = false;
        $this->editedProductIndex = $productIndex;
    }

    public function addProduct()
    {
        $this->editedProductIndex = null;
        $this->showAddForm = true;
    }

    public function cancelAddProduct()
    {
        $this->showAddForm = false;
    }

    public function storeProductItems()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'selectedProduct' => 'required|numeric|exists:products,id',
            'unit_of_measure_item_id' => 'required|numeric|exists:unit_of_measure_items,id',
            'quantity' => 'required',
            'unit_cost' => 'required',
            'total_cost' => 'required',
        ]);

        $this->incoming_stock->IncomingStockProducts()->create([
            'product_id' => $this->selectedProduct,
            'unit_of_measure_item_id' => $this->unit_of_measure_item_id,
            'quantity' => $this->quantity,
            'unit_cost' => $this->unit_cost,
            'total_cost' => $this->total_cost,
        ]);

        $this->showAddForm = false;
        $this->products = $this->incoming_stock->IncomingStockProducts->load('product')->toArray();
    }
}
```

[image: What happened after clicking the add product button]

Please help. TIA

Tried to put wire:ignore to the form tag and also put a wire:key on the form tr but still the same.

Answer (score 1):

solved it by just adding wire:click on the save button and call the method to save the data instead of using the form's wire:submit.